# Why doesn't a django sqlite3 database work the same on one machine vs the other?

Tags: django, database, sqlite, heroku, django-models

I'm working on learning Django, but I've run into to a problem with my database not transferring correctly (or it's transferring correctly and I'm missing something, which is what I think is happening).

I have a Django model `Link` in `models.py`

```
class Link(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    alt = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dest = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.FilePathField(path='static/misc/link_in_bio/img/')
    def __str__(self):
        title = self.title + ' Link'
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title', )
```

Then I made instances of this model and confirmed they are entered into the database correctly. They are then referenced in a page's html like so:

```
{% for link in links %}
<div id="space">
    <div class="w3-container">
        <div class="w3-panel" style="padding: 0.06em">
            <button class="block" type="button" title="{{link.title}}" onclick="window.open('{{link.dest}}')">
                <img src="../{{link.image}}" alt="{{link.alt}}" style="max-height: 7em">
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

On my development machine everything works exactly as expected and shows this:
[image: correct screen]

Then, when I deploy it on Heroku, everything builds correctly, `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` run correctly, but when I view the page it simply shows this:[image: incorrect screen]

I also can't login to the admin page with the superuser I already created on the first machine, and I know this is related but I'm not sure how to approach it. Is there some step to load and initialize the database or something?

Full code is on github [here](https://github.com/AllHailTheSheep/site_master/tree/deployment) if it helps.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That happens because their architecture filesystem isn't good for SQLite3 and results in no data at all on a regular basis, making your database empty.

The Heroku Dev Center has an [entire page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3) on the subject. Quoting the relevant portions:

> Heroku’s Cedar stack has an ephemeral filesystem. You can write to it,
> and you can read from it, but the contents will be cleared
> periodically. If you were to use SQLite on Heroku, you would lose your
> entire database at least once every 24 hours.
>
> Even if Heroku’s disks were persistent running SQLite would still not
> be a good fit. Since SQLite does not run as a service, each dyno would
> run a separate running copy. Each of these copies need their own disk
> backed store. This would mean that each dyno powering your app would
> have a different set of data since the disks are not synchronized.

Heroku suggests to use PostgreSQL in production, and you will find a lot of resources talking about how to use it instead of SQLite on Heroku.

You can also use the platform PythonAnywhere that supports SQLite3 if you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought it was a Django issue, and for some reason Heroku completely slipped my mind even though that now seems like the obvious culprit. The bounty is yours as soon as I can award it (t-minus 22 hours).  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use postgreSQL in development environment. If you do not want to get dirty your development environment just try with a docker container:

https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

```
docker run --name postgres -v postgresql-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
```

So, your development environment will be closer to production (try to use the same version too).